# Why does passing in an array of async functions to Promise.all work as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

```
await Promise.all(
  arr_tar.map(async (tar) => {
    return {
      n: await tar_get_one(tar),
      name: tar.name,
    };
  })
)
```

Why is the code above. There elements of the input array are `async` functions, but they are not invoked by anything.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: you're passing an array of Promises, not an array of async functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In the code shown, `Array#map` will call the `async` callback function on each element of the array and since `async` functions return `Promise`s the result will be an array of `Promise`s. `Promise.all` takes an iterable of `Promise`s as input so this works.

Comment: thx, I guess I was just dumb not to realize this basic javascript result.